# Trying to remove files listed in file with AppleScript with do shell script call

Tags: applescript, bash

The following code is an example of what I'm using at the moment, but it keeps erroring out on me:

```
do shell script "find /Applications -name 'Bingo.app' > /tmp/remove_files" with administrator privileges
if exists "/tmp_malware_alternate" then
    do shell script ("for i in `cat /tmp/remove_files`; do rm -rf $i") with administrator privileges
    do shell script "rm -rf /tmp/remove_files" with administrator privileges
end if
```

It's supposed to find the existence of a file *(in this case, `Bingo.app`)* and write it to a temporary file *(/tmp/remove_files)*, which it does, and then check to see if the temporary file was written. If it was, it will look into that temporary file, and delete each file *(specified by `i`)* in the temporary file listing, then remove the temporary file itself.

Instead, all it ever does is return an error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

or

```
error "/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file" number 2
```

What am I missing in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close the `for` loop:

```
do shell script ("for i in \`cat /tmp/remove_files\`; do rm -rf $i") with administrator privileges
```

should be:

```
do shell script ("for i in \`cat /tmp/remove_files\`; do rm -rf $i; done") with administrator privileges
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of it that way. I will check this when I get home tonight.

Comment: These AppleScript commands are incorrect. They have antislashes, which are not present in the question of @Danijel.